# MySQL Fails to Reinstall (Ubuntu 12.10 Server)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu

I'm running a Wordpress installation on an Ubuntu 12.10 server. The site was running fantastically until we had sporadic MySQL issues, where the site would "whitescreen" for a few hours, then return to normal.

Someone who *should not* have been toying around with the server removed MySQL to attempt a reinstall, and now mySQL refuses to reinstall. I get the following errors when running `sudo apt-get install -f mysql-server` from root.

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.10.2) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
```

In addition, I couldn't connect to MySQL through the socket before this all happened.

Things I've tried, as recommended here/on other websites:

- Restarting mysqld Deleting and (attempting) reinstallation of mysql-server
- deleting all files shown when running `dpkg -S etc/mysql`
- `apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5`
- `apt-get auto cleans`
- `apt-get with the -f flag`
- Numerous server reboots and restarts
- Tears

Comment: might be better suited for SuperUser as opposed to SO?  Involves mysql so maybe it still belongs here, but you'd probably find more help with it there...

Comment: AskUbuntu would probably be a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried entering this through terminal/PuTTy?

```
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```